# Want to check fields for data fast

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a database setup that consists of two parts: a static structure, and dynamic additions.  For each database, the dynamic can be different, and sometimes we don't have  data for all the dynamic fields.  Rigt now, we check for empties by looking at the total count of records in the entire table, but we want to move to a more refined method of checking for empties if possible.  Is it possible to quickly check through several hundred fields and see which ones are empty and which ones are populated?

Comment: By empty, do you mean NULL valued for all rows?

Comment: fields can be null or can have '' (empty string) in them, though I want to focus on nulls for now and then get empties looked at later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For searching for any rows that have NULLS in any column you can do this, first create this proc which is based on the code here [Search all columns in all the tables in a database for a specific value](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#2)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindMyData_StringNull
    @DataToFind NVARCHAR(4000),
    @ExactMatch BIT = 0
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Temp TABLE(RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1), SchemaName sysname, TableName sysname, ColumnName SysName, DataType VARCHAR(100), DataFound BIT)

    INSERT  INTO @Temp(TableName,SchemaName, ColumnName, DataType)
    SELECT  C.Table_Name,C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.Column_Name, C.Data_Type
    FROM    Information_Schema.Columns AS C
            INNER Join Information_Schema.Tables AS T
                ON C.Table_Name = T.Table_Name
        AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
    WHERE   Table_Type = 'Base Table'



DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @MAX INT
DECLARE @TableName sysname
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @PARAMETERS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @DataExists BIT
DECLARE @SQLTemplate NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT  @SQLTemplate = 'If Exists(Select *
                                          From   ReplaceTableName
                                          Where  Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName])
                                                       IS NULL
                                          )
                                     Set @DataExists = 1
                                 Else
                                     Set @DataExists = 0'
                            ,
        @PARAMETERS = '@DataExists Bit OUTPUT',
        @i = 1

SELECT @i = 1, @MAX = MAX(RowId)
FROM   @Temp

WHILE @i <= @MAX
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @SQL = REPLACE(REPLACE(@SQLTemplate, 'ReplaceTableName', QUOTENAME(SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TableName)), 'ReplaceColumnName', ColumnName)
        FROM    @Temp
        WHERE   RowId = @i


        PRINT @SQL
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, @PARAMETERS, @DataExists = @DataExists OUTPUT

        IF @DataExists =1
            UPDATE @Temp SET DataFound = 1 WHERE RowId = @i

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

SELECT  SchemaName,TableName, ColumnName
FROM    @Temp
WHERE   DataFound = 1
```

Call it like this

```
FindMyData_StringNull NULL,1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are just checking for whether or not there are any non-NULL values in the column, using EXISTS should generally be faster than getting a COUNT(*). The COUNT needs to scan the whole table to come up with the correct number. EXISTS just needs to find one row that satisfies the condition before it stops looking.

If the whole column is NULL then the time will be about the same, but in all of those cases where you have values it could be substantially shorter.

Answer (score 0):

From [Search all columns in all the tables in a database for a specific value](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/the-ten-most-asked-sql-server-questions--1#2)

first create this function

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindMyData_String
    @DataToFind NVARCHAR(4000),
    @ExactMatch BIT = 0
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Temp TABLE(RowId INT IDENTITY(1,1), SchemaName sysname, TableName sysname, ColumnName SysName, DataType VARCHAR(100), DataFound BIT)

    INSERT  INTO @Temp(TableName,SchemaName, ColumnName, DataType)
    SELECT  C.Table_Name,C.TABLE_SCHEMA, C.Column_Name, C.Data_Type
    FROM    Information_Schema.Columns AS C
            INNER Join Information_Schema.Tables AS T
                ON C.Table_Name = T.Table_Name
        AND C.TABLE_SCHEMA = T.TABLE_SCHEMA
    WHERE   Table_Type = 'Base Table'
            And Data_Type In ('ntext','text','nvarchar','nchar','varchar','char')


DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @MAX INT
DECLARE @TableName sysname
DECLARE @ColumnName sysname
DECLARE @SchemaName sysname
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @PARAMETERS NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @DataExists BIT
DECLARE @SQLTemplate NVARCHAR(4000)

SELECT  @SQLTemplate = CASE WHEN @ExactMatch = 1
                            THEN 'If Exists(Select *
                                          From   ReplaceTableName
                                          Where  Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName])
                                                       = ''' + @DataToFind + '''
                                          )
                                     Set @DataExists = 1
                                 Else
                                     Set @DataExists = 0'
                            ELSE 'If Exists(Select *
                                          From   ReplaceTableName
                                          Where  Convert(nVarChar(4000), [ReplaceColumnName])
                                                       Like ''%' + @DataToFind + '%''
                                          )
                                     Set @DataExists = 1
                                 Else
                                     Set @DataExists = 0'
                            END,
        @PARAMETERS = '@DataExists Bit OUTPUT',
        @i = 1

SELECT @i = 1, @MAX = MAX(RowId)
FROM   @Temp

WHILE @i <= @MAX
    BEGIN
        SELECT  @SQL = REPLACE(REPLACE(@SQLTemplate, 'ReplaceTableName', QUOTENAME(SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(TableName)), 'ReplaceColumnName', ColumnName)
        FROM    @Temp
        WHERE   RowId = @i


        PRINT @SQL
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL, @PARAMETERS, @DataExists = @DataExists OUTPUT

        IF @DataExists =1
            UPDATE @Temp SET DataFound = 1 WHERE RowId = @i

        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

SELECT  SchemaName,TableName, ColumnName
FROM    @Temp
WHERE   DataFound = 1
```

Now call it like this for rows with empty strings in any string type columns

```
exec FindMyData_String '',1
```

it will give you an output with column name, table name and schema name
Just keep in mind that it will search all tables

Comment: Now this is the kind of thing that while loops were invented for.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the simplest solution is to use the CHECKSUM function. First you would want to determine the checksum on an empty row and then compare that to the other rows.

```
Select Checksum(*)
From Table
```

The catch with using `*` here is that it will include the PK. You would likely have to specify the individual columns excluding the PK to get an accurate read. So something like:

```
Select Checksum(Col1, Col2, Col3)
From Table
```

[Checksum Function.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx)